# Declared global variable isn't changed inside of function

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I've looked at several similar pieces of code [on at the PHP documentation site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), and yet this example simply refuses to work.

```
$catalog = 0; // initialize variable outside of function scope

function catalog_init() 
{
  global $catalog;
  if (!file_exists ("cd_catalog.xml")){

    $xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><catalog></catalog>";
    $catalog = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
    $catalog->asXML('cd_catalog.xml');
  } else
    $catalog = simplexml_load_file("cd_catalog.xml");
}

catalog_init(); // should initialize $catalog, but doesn't.
```

After calling catalog_init(), $catalog is still 0. I know globals are generally frowned upon, but this is for a small school assignment. Can anyone figure out why this doesn't work?

Comment: whats wrong with `catalog_init($catalog); `

Comment: I know that will work, but that's kind of avoiding the issue, isn't it? I want to know *why* this doesn't work.

Comment: sorry i just don't care why code that shouldn't be used is not working.

Comment: "Outside of function scope" isn't always the same as the "global scope".

Answer (score 0):

```
$catalogue = 0;
$catalogue = catalogue_init($catalogue);
function catalogue_init($catalogue) {
    //your function content
    return $catalogue;
}
```

You function return nothing. Pass $catalogue as a parameter and remove global $catalogue